# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence \u

Tags: jsp, unicode, jstl, jstl-functions

I have a JSP which is used to display location in UI form where JSTL code is been used,

```
function setLocation() {
      var fullPath = "${fn:escapeXml(folderPath)}";
      updateFolderPath(fullPath);
    
  }
```

the folderPath value is "university_stores\university" which is coming from form,
but fn:escapeXml is failing and giving "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence" as fullPath is becoming "university_stores\university" after the escapeXml function is executed and jsp gets loaded to UI

Can someone help me to fix this issue or is there any ulternate I can use for escapeXml,
I tried splitting the string and concating again but didnt worked

Comment: Hi, JavaScript != XML. You need to escape for JavaScript, not for XML :) See abovelinked duplicate.

Comment: @BalusC I tried this 
var fullPath = "<%= org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript((String) folderPath) %>";
but it is giving error saying folderPath is not defined but I have folderPath as a var in the function 
var folderPath = getForm().folderPath.value;
Can you tell me how to add a folderPath to escapeEcmaScript function

Comment: Simply use `${...}` as instructed in the abovelinked duplicate instead of old fashioned `<%...%>` practice of previous century.

Comment: @BalusC okay it worked but my question is that functionality wise escapeXml and escapeEcmaScript same like when we use esacpeXml and if it encounters any value like <,>,& it replaces to '<': return '&lt;';'>': return '&gt;';'&': return '&amp;';'\'': return '&apos;';'"': return '&quot;';
will escapeEcmaScript will do the same thing?